# regex problem with Ctrl-M

Tags: java, regex

I want to macth the following:

```
boolean b = "\u000D".matches("\\cM");
```

but the compiler give me:

```
unclosed string literal
illegal character: \92
illegal character: \92
unclosed string literal
not a statement
```

why? that literal is not a valid unicode Ctrl-m unicode code???

Comment: Have you tried \\cm? I dont think the regex for control characters should be case-insensitive, but the compiler might be looking for a lowercase character.

Answer (score 3):

The problem of `unclosed string literal` is because [the `\uXXXX` sequences are resolved *before* lexing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#95504). So

```
boolean b = "\u000D".matches("\\cM");
```

becomes

```
boolean b = "
".matches("\\cM");
```

which is invalid Java code. (yes it also means you could write `String foo = \u0022\u0021\u0022;` and compiles correctly.)

If you write instead

```
boolean b = "\r".matches("\\cM"); // \r == \u000D
```

then the code works and return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Haha !

This is a trap!

Java processes Unicode escapes **before** interpretation.
So, it converts you code into:

```
boolean b = "
".matches("\\cM");
```

.. and so, it is definitely an error - incompleted string and so on.

Comment: Ups ! I have unswered simultaneously with other guy!

Comment: Not simultaneously, you're 47 seconds slower :p

Comment: I swear that I have not looked at you solution :) Though you answer is more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

This might be unrelated, but I wanted to remove <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> from a field in database (Vertica).

I used below function and it worked for me.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(<column_name>,'[[:cntrl:]]')
```